# VB.NET syntax and string Extension Methods

Tags: .net, vb.net, syntax

Code in VB.NET

```
Module Utils
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Sub Print(ByVal message As String)
    Console.WriteLine(message)
End Sub
End Module

Public Class Foo
Public Sub New()
    Dim test = "cucu"
    test.Print() ' no problem: custom string extension method '
    "cucu".Print() ' syntax error '
End Sub
End Class
```

1) First problem, I'd prefer to be able to use "cucu".MyExtensionMethod() as well as test.MyExtensionMethod();

1')
Syntax like

```
  "No Result".Print() ' Print is an extension method '
  " No Result ".Trim() ' Trim is a framework method '
```

does not work both of them

However, syntax like

```
  myTextBox.Text = "No Result".Translate() ' Translate is an extension method '
  myTextBox.Text = " No Result ".Trim() ' Trim is a framework method '
```

works very well.

So seems some consistency miss of the string constant behavior.

2) Have a look on the COMMENTS (in the attached picture). The words "custom", "string" and "error" are highlighted, however they are in the comments, so should be green, not blue.

Why this? What workaround?

EDIT:

Declared as "bug" in [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/686166/vb-net-syntax-and-string-extension-methods) (even if is not more that a syntactic "miss")...

EDIT 2:

As remarked Hans Passant, standard string methods, like `"cucu".Trim()` does not work either.

Comment: Um, the workaround is to assign it to a variable as you did with `test`?

Comment: @BoltClock )))) ok, why this? ))

Comment: How are you so sure it's a bug already?

Comment: Please edit your bug report to include a complete “working” sample with step-by-step instructions how to reproduce it. Otherwise it’s unlikely that Microsoft will bother with it.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with extension methods, "blah ".Trim() doesn't work either.

Comment: @Hans Passant: so, you think, Microsoft can't "fix" that inconvenient?

Comment: What on Earth is the point of asking *me*.  I merely think you're making a mountain out of a mole hill, as usual.

Comment: @Hans: Because I know you as a smart guy, Hans... ) We know that in C# this "feature" is not present, anyway...

Comment: @Hans Passant: not really, in fact; `myTextBox.Text = " No result ".Trim()` works very well, as well as `myTextBox.Text = " No result ".Translate()`, by the way...

Answer (score 10):

I can confirm this is indeed a “bug” (tested in Visual Studio 2008). But in fact, it’s by design in VB and won’t be changed.

However, I’d like to take the time to explain why *this is a horrible question*. Sorry Serhio.

1. It doesn’t list all steps necessary to reproduce the problem.
2. It doesn’t provide the complete code.
3. It doesn’t reduce the problem to the minimal (don’t use `Infer` here – it detracts from the problem)
4. As a consequence, there are a hundred different reasons that would *completely* explain this behaviour, without a bug (for an example, see stakx’ excellent (now deleted) answer).

Here’s a complete example, using the default settings for VB, that doesn’t have these problems (create a new empty console project solution and paste this code into `Module1.vb`):

```
Module Extensions
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Sub ShowDialog(ByVal message As String)
        Console.WriteLine(message)
    End Sub
End Module

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim s As String = "Hello"
        s.ShowDialog()
        ' Doesn’t work:
        '"World".ShowDialog()
        ' Works:
        Call "World".ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Module
```

The behaviour is consistent in VB: you cannot have a value as the first token in a logical line. For instance, the following code also doesn’t compile (given an existing, appropriate, definition of a form class `Form1`):

```
New Form1().ShowDialog()
```

and once again the fix is to prefix the expression by `Call`:

```
Call New Form1().ShowDialog()
```

Comment: fixed some of your remarks )...  I know this is not maybe a real question. I just would like to share this "problem".

Answer (score 3):

You can do `CStr("cucu").ShowDialog()`